# POCO C++ MongoDB: convert std::string to MongoDB::Document

Tags: c++, json, mongodb, poco-libraries

How can I make the following conversion:

```
std::string json_str;
Poco::MongoDB::Document document();
document.fromString(json_str);
```

I didn't found any method like "fromString".

I would also like to customize the add and get functions for Document, in Poco there is not a word about it.

```
template<typename T>
struct ElementTraits<std::vector<T>>
{
    enum { TypeId = 0x00005;};

    static std::string toString(const std::vector<T>& value, int indent = 0)
    {
        return models::ModelBase::toString(value);
    }
};


template<typename T>
inline void BSONReader::read<std::vector<T>>(std::vector<T>& to)
{
    Poco::MongoDb::Array mongo_array();
    for(const auto& element: to) mongo_array.add(element);
    read(mongo_array);
}


template<typename T>
inline void BSONWriter::write<std::vector<T>>(std::vector<T>& from)
{
    Poco::MongoDb::Array mongo_array();
    for(const auto& element: to) mongo_array.add(element);
    write(mongo_array);
}
```

Judging by what I found, this is how you can customize some class, but if you look closely, you will see an error - it is impossible to perform a partial specialization of the second and third methods

Comment: Use the `read` method.

Comment: @D.SM I showed an example of specialization of this method above, but obviously this does not work, since this is a partial specialization

Comment: read operates on a reader which uses an istream. I don't know what you are attempting to do  with a vector as read argument.